# Returning vector of smaller length to an already populated Vector

Tags: c++, vector, return

I have a vector filled with x number of values, but i need to iterate a function several times using the initial vector, but returning a vector of potentially less values each time. Here's where I've got to currently, currently the vector keeps all the values and i'm not sure how to either override the initial vector declaration or remove items from that initial vector efficiently.

```
for (auto& image : images)
    {
        rValues.push_back(image->pixels[pix].r);
        gValues.push_back(image->pixels[pix].g);
        bValues.push_back(image->pixels[pix].b);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        float rMedian = calculateMedian(rValues);
        float rsD = calculateStandardDeviation(rValues);
        rValues = sigmaClip(rValues, rsD, rMedian);


        for (auto& r : rValues)
        {
            std::cout << "r val : " << r << "\n";
        }
        system("pause");
    }
```

(Ignore the `std::cout` of the rValues, was using this to check if values were being removed each iteration).

Then this is what I have implemented in the sigmaClip function that is the one that needs to return a vector of a different length.

```
std::vector<float> sigmaClip(std::vector<float> values, float sD, float median)
{
    //Sigma Clip
    float upperBound = median + sD;
    float lowerBound = median - sD;
    std::vector<float> returnVals;
    for (auto& val : values)
    {
        if ((val > lowerBound) && (val < upperBound))
            returnVals.push_back(val);
    }

    return returnVals;
}
```

I tried initially using .erase() and remove_if on the vector being passed into `sigmaClip()` but I don't think these functions worked as I intended, hence creating another vector within `sigmaClip()` and returning that in hopes it would override the initial rValues vector.

Comment: If the goal is to mutate the `vector` passed to `sigmaClip`, make it a reference parameter, and `std::remove_if` should work just fine on it with no need to create a new `vector`, and therefore no need continually replace the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::remove_if` should do the job just fine if paired with the `erase` method to effect [the erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). Redefine `sigmaClip` to accept a mutable reference to `values` (rather than returning it), and something like:

```
void sigmaClip(std::vector<float>& values, float sD, float median)
{
    //Sigma Clip
    const float upperBound = median + sD;
    const float lowerBound = median - sD;
    values.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(values), std::end(values),
                                [=](float val) { return val < lowerBound || val > upperBound; }),
                 std::end(values));
}
```

should work fine, changing the call site to:

```
// Remove assignment back to rValues
sigmaClip(rValues, rsD, rMedian);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried implementing what you suggested above, but the cout still seems to print all the values. Not sure if you know about sigma clipping. But i'm trying to iterate through the initial vector multiple times removing outliers and after x iterations taking the mean from the remain values. I think what you've suggested is along the right lines of what i'm trying to accomplish though.

Comment: Is it to do with the way i'm declaringthe rValues vector?
`std::vector<float> rValues;
std::vector<float> gValues;
std::vector<float> bValues;`

Comment: @publicMan: Did you note the change in `sigmaClip`'s prototype? It now accepts the `vector` by mutable reference (`std::vector<float>&`), not by value (`std::vector<float>&`). If you accept it by value, the removal will only affect the copy in `sigmaClip`, not the caller copy; accepting by reference means you can edit the caller's `vector` in-place.

Comment: Yes, I've change sigmaClip to accept `&values`. But it still doesn't seem to be removing the values from the vector. Sorry for not understanding, I'm new to c++ with the whole passing by reference etc.

Comment: Put some print outs at various points and it seems as though the remove_if is not doing anything.

Comment: @publicMan: Ah, I forgot an important part. `std::remove_if` doesn't delete from the end, it just returns the end iterator after removal having copied or moved the values beyond it into the reduced area. You need to use the `erase` method of your sequence to trim it back (passing the return value of `std::remove_if` as the begin iterator for erasure, and the original end iterator as the end point). I've edited to include that. Also, I realized I typoed in my comment; meant to say "not by value (std::vector<float>)." (the value version obviously shouldn't use `&`)

Comment: Thanks! Working now, seemed there was another issue with my standard Deviation function that was passing incorrect values but is sorted now. Many thanks.

Comment: @publicMan: FYI, the edit (which I accepted) makes this behave differently from your original code. Since your original code was testing what to *keep* via `> lowerBound` and `< upperBound`, the matching test for what to *reject* should test `<= lowerBound` or `>= upperBound`. Changing it to `< lowerBound`/`> upperBound` implies your original logic was also incorrect in the case of a value exactly at the bounds.

Comment: I think i understand what you're saying and have no doubt my original logic was flawed. Thanks anyways though, you've been a great help understanding the `remove_if` and `erase` methods

Comment: @publicMan: You're welcome. Make sure to read [the Wiki page on the erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) for full explanation and fleshed out examples. It's a neat trick; manages to do the cut down in place with no additional memory, `O(n)` work, it can work on subsets of a container (filtering only the 5th through 50th elements of a 1000 long sequence), and on C++11 and higher, for "good" `move` capable objects, the `O(n)` work is pretty cheap (only the destructors of the defunct objects are likely to do any meaningful work).